# What to do about unrendered LATEX in newsletters?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, newsletter

As MathJax requires JavaScript to render, it can't be rendered inside an email as emails don't allow the execution of arbitrary JavaScript.

This is a problem for readers of the MathExchange newsletter readers.

What can be done to handle this pain point?

My suggestion is to add a "Open in browser" button at the end of such emails. This link should open the newsletter as a webpage on the MathExchange website.

Comment: I'll just mention that MathJax isn't rendered in the preview available on the Stack Exchange website: https://stackexchange.com/digests and https://math.stackexchange.com/digest/preview - however, the point about Javascript is relevant only for emails.

Comment: It would be helpful to link to info on the newsletter since it is likely not well known.

Comment: @BillDubuque and csmathhc: Some basic info on newsletters can be found [in the corresponding tag-info in this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/newsletter/info). Maybe this could be added as a source of information on newsleters (a.k.a. digests). And maybe there are some other sources which might be useful.